# Placing Buttons on a status notification

Tags: java, android, oop, user-interface

I would like to put two buttons on my notifications from the status bar. Of course they do not appear until the user touches to expand them. I have created the custom layout for my notification using RemoteViews but am unsure if it's possible to obtain a reference to them because of my current code structure.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.w("C2DMReceiver",
            "Message Received, this is the message with no payload");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String[] payload = new String[3];
        payload[0] = (String) extras.get("payload");
        payload[1] = (String) extras.get("payload2");
        SharedPreferences sharedP = Prefs.get(this);
        boolean inApp = sharedP.getBoolean("currentlyInApp", true);
        if (!inApp) {
            createNotification(context, payload);
        }

    }
}

public void createNotification(Context context, String[] payload) {
    SharedPreferences sharedP = Prefs.get(context);
    boolean needsToLogin = sharedP
            .getBoolean("loginFromNotification", true);

    Log.w("C2DMReceiver", "createNotification called");

    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
    Intent notificationIntent2 = new Intent(this, UniteActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent;
    if (needsToLogin) {
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent2,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    } else {
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    }

    // Compatibility builder
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    RemoteViews remote = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification);


    //Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.notification);

    notification.setAutoCancel(false);
    notification.setContent(remote);
    notification.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setTicker(payload[0]);
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default1);
    notification.setContentTitle(payload[1]);
    notification.setContentText(payload[0]);



    long duration[] = { 100, 300, 100 };
    notification.setVibrate(duration);

    notificationmanager.notify(0, notification.getNotification());
}
```

onMessage is a method pulled from the Google C2DM library where the notifications are generated by intents received from google. Without a view, how can I obtain a reference to my buttons using findViewById()? or some other means

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the method:

[RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(int, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

---

So, if you add...

```
remote.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pIntent);
```

...it should work.